# Can we use ".so" library compiled for Linux into android?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am writing a wrapper class for C++ ".so". I want to use the library in Java application and Android app using JNI. So I have to create header file and cpp file which will do JNI calls. 
I could use that on Linux in Java application.

The steps I followed:

1. Created java class and called native functions in that class

   ```
   public class TestWrapper { 
       static {
           System.load("/home/native.so");    
   }         
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new TestWrapper().TestWrapper();    
   } 
       private native void sayHello();
   }
   ```
2. Created header file and cpp file. CCP contains following code

   ```
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestWrapper_sayHello(JNIEnv *, jobject){
   uint16_t data = 0;
   void (*func_print_name)(const uint16_t*);   
   void* handle = dlopen("libCppTobeUsed.so.0", RTLD_LAZY);
   if (handle){
       *(void**)(&func_print_name) = dlsym(handle, function_name);    
       func_print_name(&data);
       dlclose(handle);
       std::cout << "data received .." << data << std::endl;
     }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Compiled this **cpp** class and generated "native.so"

This is working fine. The "native.so" could call the fuction form "ibCppTobeUsed.so.0" when called from TestWrapper.java.

I want to use same library for android as well. So, I have to write wrapper class all over again in Android NDK? Or I can compile my "native.so" for Android platform?

If I try to use it directly, I get error

> "install_failed_no_matching_abis".

Comment: In what [CPU architecture or Application Binary Interface (ABI)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) is your `.so` written in? If it was compiled for Linux it could be x86 or x64 which won't run on ARM devices.

Comment: Compiled for x86. So, I need to rewrite the wrapper class in android NDK?

Comment: You'll need to recompile the C/C++ code that created the `.so` with the NDK. The JNI wrapper classes need to be done for all architectures regardless.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the same shared library. Android is not GNU. You need to compile your libraries for Android.

> So, I have to write wrapper class all over again in Android NDK?

No, you can write it in a way that works for both. You need to factor our your JNI wrapper class from your `main` class, since Android uses `Activity` instead of `main`.

I would also **strongly** recommend against ever relying on `dlclose` on any platform. The API is not sound, and will lead to surprising behavior with modern C++. A single global  `thread_local` with a non-trivial destructor renders the library un-unloadable, so the next `dlopen` will not reset library state as you might expect. If you need to implement initialization/finalization logic for your library, make explicit `Initialize` and `Finalize` functions a part of the libary and call them directly.

Without knowing your architecture's full architecture I can't be sure, but from the sample you've given here I'd recommend dropping the `dlopen`/`dlsym` from your JNI entirely and just link against `libCppTobeUsed` directly.